# Change the path prefix of the destination

Tags: abap

I have a destination created automatically by some program.

Now I want to change the path prefix of the destination programmatically during runtime. Is this possible ?

I was going through this documentation

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/1f/93163f9959a808e10000000a114084/content.htm?no_cache=true

This mentions that if the path prefix is not mentioned then the URI can be changed. So I had a destination without path prefix and then I tried using method "if_http_utility~set_request_uri", but this also did not work.

Code sample attached

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report http_destination_program
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
REPORT http_destination_program.
    
DATA client type ref to if_http_client.
DATA cl_http_util type ref to cl_http_utility.
DATA dest type rfcdest.
DATA gv_subrc  TYPE sysubrc.
DATA uri type string.
DATA timeout type I.
DATA errortext type string.
   
uri = '/do/b/json'.
DEST = 'SAP'.
errortext = ' Cannot connect to server'.
timeout = 0.
    
CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_destination
    exporting destination = dest
    importing client      = client
    exceptions
      others              = 6.
    
cl_http_utility=>set_request_uri( request = client->request uri = uri ).
gv_subrc = cl_http_utility=>get_last_error( ).
IF gv_subrc <> 0.
  WRITE: / 'Wrong URI format'.
  EXIT.
ENDIF.
write 'Hello Saurav'.
    
    
call method client->send
      exporting  timeout = timeout
      exceptions others  = 4.
    
if sy-subrc <> 0.
  call method client->get_last_error
         importing code    = gv_subrc
                   message = errortext.
  write: / 'communication_error( send )',
         / 'code: ', gv_subrc, 'message: ', 'test'.
endif.
    
    
call method client->receive
        exceptions others = 4.

if sy-subrc <> 0.
  call method client->get_last_error
         importing code    = gv_subrc
                   message = errortext.
  write: / 'communication_error( receive )',
         / 'code: ', gv_subrc, 'message: ', 'test'.
endif.
```

I am not an expert in ABAP and ABAP HTTP framework . Can you please provide some hints on how can I achieve my scenario ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: `CL_HTTP_CLIENT=>CREATE_BY_DESTINATION` + `CL_HTTP_UTILITY=>SET_REQUEST_URI` should work. Please provide your code sample and give more details where it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the response...code sample is attached..i purposefully gave a wrong URI but still the send method is returning 0 as response

Comment: It's impossible to know whether it works because you don't read the response after receiving -> `data(response) = client->response->get_cdata( ).`

Comment: Question asked also in the SAP forum: https://answers.sap.com/questions/682182/change-the-path-prefix-of-the-destination.html

Comment: thanks a ton.....i thought the send/receive methods itself would throw the errors...but their errors are actually about establishing the connection of http client...to check the response's error we need to check the response object of http client

Comment: Another question was whether a destination with an existing configured path prefix be updated with a new path prefix programmatically ?..at least through my code i could not achieve this

Comment: I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know whether the HTTP request works, you should read the response after receiving :

```
call method client->receive
...
data(response) = client->response->get_cdata( ). " <== missing part
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "path prefix" of the RFC destination (transaction SM59) can't be ignored at runtime, because the customizing done by an administrator shouldn't be ignored by programs.

(I don't have any official reference for argumenting, I only did a test to confirm your finding)

This can be seen like low-level commands of the operating system, an administrator will define the ones allowed to be used by ABAP programs in transaction SM49, the other commands can't be used.

Moreover, the other data of the RFC destination may only be valid for this path prefix (authentication for instance).

If a program should be allowed to access any path, then the administrator should be asked to leave the path prefix empty.

Comment: Your comments makes sense...thanks for the analysis done Sandra

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead:

```
cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
  EXPORTING
    url                = lv_url
  IMPORTING
    client             = DATA(lo_http_client)
  EXCEPTIONS
    argument_not_found = 1
    plugin_not_active  = 2
    internal_error     = 3
    OTHERS             = 4 ).
```

It's more convenient for changing URLs.

Comment: thanks for the response but my requirement is more on the destination part since i have to work with an existing destination in my code